# how do i put my contacts into edittext?

Tags: android, eclipse

GOOD DAY!

i am newbie in programming and trying to learn new things. To explain Clearly my question is i have this button that looks to contact and by clicking the contact the app will display the number in toast. i just can't understand yet how to make it text to display in edittext.

here is my code.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_s);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectContact)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);                
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                        null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String number = c.getString(0);
                    int type = c.getInt(1);
                    showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
    Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

i did a deep search for this but as a beginner i need some help to understand more java. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your editText name is `showname` then use

In `onCreate()` method

```
EditText showname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xml_id_of_your_text);
```

And in the method to show desired text

```
public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
showname.setText(""+type + ": " + number+"");
}
```

Comment: thank you the method worked but i have changed some parts inside the onCreate i declare this con1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cnum1); and before the onCreate i declare EditText con1; then it worked! thank you again.